# Let $A$ be a set of real numbers and let $B = \{−x : x ∈ A\}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find a relation between $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ and a relation between $\inf A$ and $\sup B$.

I know that $\sup B = - \inf A$ and $\inf B = - \sup A$ but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you tell us what you think of the question and what you tried? Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: Let's look at a small simple example... if $A = \{\color{blue}{-1},1,3,5,\color{red}{7}\}$ then $B = \{\color{blue}{-7},-5,-3,-1,\color{red}{1}\}$... Notice my use of color...

Comment: "*I know that sup B = -inf A ... but I do not know how to prove it*"  Use your definitions.  Use the fact that if $x<y$ then $-x>-y$

Answer (score 0):

Let, $M = sup A$  and  $m = inf A$.

Then for all $x \in A \implies x\le M \implies -x \ge -M$ 
  ...$(1)$

Now for arbitrary $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is $x_\epsilon \in A$ s.t. $x_\epsilon\gt M-\epsilon \implies -x_\epsilon+\epsilon \lt - M $   ....$(2)$

From (1) and (2) you can see that $-M= inf B$   i.e.   $inf B = - sup A$.

Similarly you can prove the other one.